# Is it possible to have a ternary relationship with two weak entities?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a relational DataBase (MYSQL) to register users of a platform. I'd like to register which users can actually drive cars, so I create two tables: User(User_id) and Driver(User_id). The driver entity doesn't have any additional attributes, so I assume it is a weak entity, being User_id its primary key and adding a Foreign Key in order to link it to User table.I have an additional entity, Driving License(User_Id,Date_of_Issue), which is also a weak entity depending on Users to be identified. Every Driver needs to have one and only one Driving License, but **I don't know if a ternary 1:1:1 relationship can represent this properly**.

I feel it is necessary to stablish an inclusivity restriction for the two relationships. (For an user to be a Driver he/she needs to have a driving license).

This is would be the ER Diagram so far:

[image]

Thanks in advance, any help or comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Beside the point, but what does it mean to be a driver without a licence? What would you loose if  you remove the driver entity from your model? I.e, a driver is a user with a driver licence

Comment: I want to create a reflexive relationship, for instance "instructs", for drivers to give advise to other drivers. If I delete the Driver Table it will not be easy to model it. Maybe I could remove the license table and insert it as an attribute in the Driver table.

Comment: I, too, vote for getting rid of the `Driver` table.  `license` could be a `NULLable` column that is set for any `User` that is also a Driver.  At some point , you need to let go of the "model" and its restrictions and take up the "schema" (with its different restrictions).